# Component doesn't react to property change [array member accessed by index]

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I have a method in the root Vue instance that updates some data in the "data" object of that same Vue instance (see below).

**Here is my function in the methods object of the root Vue instance**

```
updateRecipe(newRecipe) {
   this.recipesArr[this.findRecipeIndex(newRecipe.id)] = newRecipe;
}
```

**Here is my data object in the root Vue instance**

```
data: {
   recipesArr: JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("storedRecipes")) // this is an array filled with objects
}
```

I then have a Vue component which has a "recipesarr" property bound to "recipesArr" in the root instance's data object.

**Here is my Vue component called "recipe-list"**

```
<recipe-list
   v-bind:recipesarr="recipesArr">
</recipe-list>
```

**Unfortunately, this Vue component doesn't react to any changes made by my "updateRecipe" function to "recipesArr". Why is this the case and how do I get it to react to changes made to "recipesArr" in the root Vue instance?**

As you can see in the image below, the "recipesarr" property has updated; however, the Vue component does not update when I change "servingsNum" from 4 to 2.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You've all fixed the problem, but we might as well write it down. **[Vue cannot detect changes to array members when you access them directly by index.](http://newRecipe)** Use splice(), or Vue.set() to modify array members, and your changes will be detected. so...

```
updateRecipe(newRecipe) {
   // Don't do this.
   this.recipesArr[this.findRecipeIndex(newRecipe.id)] = newRecipe;
   // Do this instead !
   this.recipesArr.splice(this.findRecipeIndex(newRecipe.id),1,newRecipe);
}
```